# How to drag multiple items from row those are next to each other using ng2- dragula

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I'm trying to drag multiple items from row those are next to each other and drop to another row and refill the place with the items on which the other items are dropped using ng2-dragula, I'm getting result of dragging items to another row but after dragging the item, its place remains empty. Please help me sort this issue or guide me how to achieve this task using angular 2 ng2-dragula or is there any other option to achieve this.

[image: As you can see the empty place here i want to refill the place with the item on which the other item is dropped.]

Comment: can you share some code in stackblitz or some other ways?

Comment: yeah sure find the link https://angular-s9az2v.stackblitz.io

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9az2v for code go through this link

Comment: Can you tell me what was the issue? as per your question I understood when replacing one's place get empty but with the link you provided I can't recreate the issue

Comment: have you gone through the stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9az2v this link? there i have shared the code as well. just guide me how to refill the place with item

Comment: ok let me go through

Comment: I'm still checking it meanwhile, can you look at this https://embed.plnkr.co/Y4Gy0nHuGKpaYQObXLWG/

Comment: it is not replacing the row item its just draging the item to another row

Comment: you have to swap row values right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't swap rows in this scenario. You have set the limit for days as 15 so, when you swap within the rows its perfectly alright. But when you try to swap row values it's **breaking the condition for days** Therefore rather than swapping the item get reduced at one end. As far I know you can either swap values within the rows or swap rows, can't do both. If you have any issues or doubt let me know.